# Make previous selected word go away on html and replace with new word in Hangman game for javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently making a hangman game with javascript and I am struggling with how to remove and replace the previously selected word, with a new word. Currently I ahve my code set up so that when the player guesses the word correctly, a message pops up and asks the user if they want to play again. If they press Y, I call the function that randomly selects a word from and array and also uses the push method to fill and empty array with blank lines the same length of the chosen word. But when I call this function after Y has been pressed, the previous word doesnt go away and key presses also do not register.

```
    var hangmanObject = {
    randomWords: ['rock','paper','modular synthesizer', 'led zeppelin'],
    chosenWord: "",
    numWins: 0,
    numLives: 10,

    empty: [],
    incorrect: [],
    splitArray: []

    }
   function startFunction() 
   {
    document.getElementById("numLives").innerHTML = hangmanObject.numLives;
    displayChosenWord();
   }

   function displayChosenWord()
   {
   hangmanObject.chosenWord =  hangmanObject.randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*hangmanObject.randomWords.length)]
   hangmanObject.splitArray = hangmanObject.chosenWord.split("");
   for (x = 0; x < hangmanObject.chosenWord.length; x++)
   {
    if (hangmanObject.chosenWord.charAt(x) === " ")
        hangmanObject.empty.push(" ");
    else
        hangmanObject.empty.push(" _ ");
    }

        document.getElementById("blanks").innerHTML = hangmanObject.empty.join("");
    }



    document.onkeyup = function(event) 
    {      

   var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();


   for (x = 0; x < hangmanObject.chosenWord.length; x++)
        {
            if (hangmanObject.chosenWord.charAt(x) === userGuess)
            {
                hangmanObject.empty[x] = userGuess;
                document.getElementById("blanks").innerHTML = hangmanObject.empty.join("");
            }

        }
        if (hangmanObject.splitArray.indexOf(userGuess) === -1) //checking to see if wrong letter chosen
        {
                hangmanObject.numLives--;
                document.getElementById("numLives").innerHTML = hangmanObject.numLives;
                hangmanObject.incorrect.push(userGuess);
                document.getElementById("LettersGuessed").innerHTML = hangmanObject.incorrect;
        }
        console.log(hangmanObject.empty);
        if (hangmanObject.empty.indexOf(" _ ") === -1) 
        {
            hangmanObject.numWins++;

            // console.log("i won");
            document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = hangmanObject.numWins;
            document.getElementById("Play").innerHTML = "Play Again? Y/N";
            document.onkeyup = function(event) 
            {      
               // Determines which exact key was selected. Make it lowercase
               var Choice = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
               if (Choice === 'y')
               {
                    hangmanObject.numLives = 10;
                    displayChosenWord();
               }
            }

        }
        if (hangmanObject.numLives <= 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("lose").innerHTML = "You Lose";
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `document.onkeyup` callback inside the callback, effectively disabling it for letter guesses.

Also, the `empty` array is never emptied so the next word is appended to the empty letters array from the previous word. Here's a simpler approach, by using a `gameState` flag, you can decide whether the user is entering letters to guess, or they are deciding to play again. Also, a single div for status can be used ;)

```js
var hangmanObject = {
  gameState: 'playing',
  randomWords: [
    'rock',
    'paper',
    'modular synthesizer',
    'led zeppelin'
  ],
  chosenWord: "",
  numWins: 0,
  numLives: 10,

  empty: [],
  incorrect: [],
  splitArray: []
}

function startFunction() {
  document.getElementById("numLives").innerHTML = hangmanObject.numLives;

  chooseNewWord();
}

function chooseNewWord() {
  hangmanObject.chosenWord = hangmanObject.randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * hangmanObject.randomWords.length)]
  hangmanObject.splitArray = hangmanObject.chosenWord.split("");

  // Reset guesses and misses
  hangmanObject.empty = [];
  hangmanObject.incorrect = [];

  for (x = 0; x < hangmanObject.chosenWord.length; x++) {
    if (hangmanObject.chosenWord.charAt(x) === " ")
      hangmanObject.empty.push(" ");
    else
      hangmanObject.empty.push("_");
  }

  document.getElementById("blanks").innerHTML = hangmanObject.empty.join(" ");
}


document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();

  // Game status is "playing"
  if (hangmanObject.gameState === 'playing') {
    for (x = 0; x < hangmanObject.chosenWord.length; x++) {
      if (hangmanObject.chosenWord.charAt(x) === userGuess) {
        hangmanObject.empty[x] = userGuess;

        document.getElementById("blanks").innerHTML = hangmanObject.empty.join(" ");
      }
    }

    // checking to see if wrong letter chosen
    if (hangmanObject.splitArray.indexOf(userGuess) === -1) {
      hangmanObject.numLives--;

      document.getElementById("numLives").innerHTML = hangmanObject.numLives;

      hangmanObject.incorrect.push(userGuess);

      document.getElementById("LettersGuessed").innerHTML = hangmanObject.incorrect.join(",");
    }

    // Some debug
    console.log(hangmanObject.empty);

    // WIN situation
    if (hangmanObject.empty.indexOf("_") === -1) {
      hangmanObject.numWins++;

      // Set status message and game state
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "You won " + hangmanObject.numWins + " times";
      hangmanObject.gameState = 'finished';
    }

    // LOSE situation
    if (hangmanObject.numLives <= 0) {
      // Set status message and game state
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "You Lose";
      hangmanObject.gameState = 'finished';
    }

    // Set message if game finished
    if (hangmanObject.gameState === 'finished') {
      document.getElementById("Play").innerHTML = "Play Again? Y/N";
    }

    // Game status is "finished"
  } else {
    // If user selects play again
    if (userGuess === 'y') {
      // Set status back to "playing"
      hangmanObject.gameState = 'playing';

      // Reset lives and messages
      hangmanObject.numLives = 10;

      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("LettersGuessed").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("Play").innerHTML = "";

      // Choose new word
      chooseNewWord();
    } else {
      // Set message
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Goodbye!";

      // Disable key handler
      document.onkeyup = null;
    }
  }
}

startFunction();
```

```html
<div id="numLives"></div>

<div id="blanks"></div>

<div id="LettersGuessed"></div>

<div id="status"></div>

<div id="Play"></div>
```

Comment: ahh I see. So my main problem was I was not resetting the empty array and incorrect array to empty arrays again. Thank you I will try this out

Comment: how come you cant have the if statement if (userGuess == 'y') nested inside the if statement right above it:   if (hangmanObject.gameState === 'finished') {
      document.getElementById("Play").innerHTML = "Play Again? Y/N";
    } //I tried nesting the if (userGuess == 'y') inside that if statement and then setting gameState to "playing" but the program doesnt register the keys pressed for the next word, except the letter 'n' for no. Why does it do that?

Comment: You can only evaluate the `userGuess` value once per execution of the `onkeyup` callback. This means that for every time the key up event is fired, the whole if-else tree is evaluated. 

If you take a closer look you will see that the only way the `gameState === 'finished'` can evaluate to `true` inside the `gameState === 'playing'` branch, is if it has **just changed** due to the last key pressed leading to a finished game. That's why it sets the "Play again (Y/N)" message and then it won't evaluate the 'y' or 'n' key until the next keyup event, on the 'finished' branch. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: yes that makes sense. That one was a hard one to solve. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

words joining - You need to clear the array.

no keyup - you replaced it with the 'y/n' keyup, you need to reset it.

also worth clearing the wrong letters and lives too on a new game.

see working example below:-

```js
var hangmanObject = {
  randomWords: ['rock', 'paper', 'modular synthesizer', 'led zeppelin'],
  chosenWord: "",
  numWins: 0,
  numLives: 10,

  empty: [],
  incorrect: [],
  splitArray: []

}

function startFunction() {
  document.getElementById("numLives").innerHTML = hangmanObject.numLives;
  displayChosenWord();
}

function displayChosenWord() {
  hangmanObject.empty = []; // empty the array
  hangmanObject.incorrect = [];
  hangmanObject.chosenWord = hangmanObject.randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * hangmanObject.randomWords.length)]
  hangmanObject.splitArray = hangmanObject.chosenWord.split("");
  for (x = 0; x < hangmanObject.chosenWord.length; x++) {
    if (hangmanObject.chosenWord.charAt(x) === " ")
      hangmanObject.empty.push(" ");
    else
      hangmanObject.empty.push(" _ ");
  }

  document.getElementById("blanks").innerHTML = hangmanObject.empty.join("");
  document.getElementById("LettersGuessed").innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("numLives").innerHTML = hangmanObject.numLives;
  document.onkeyup = gameKeyUp;
}



function gameKeyUp(event) {

  var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();


  for (x = 0; x < hangmanObject.chosenWord.length; x++) {
    if (hangmanObject.chosenWord.charAt(x) === userGuess) {
      hangmanObject.empty[x] = userGuess;
      document.getElementById("blanks").innerHTML = hangmanObject.empty.join("");
    }

  }
  if (hangmanObject.splitArray.indexOf(userGuess) === -1) //checking to see if wrong letter chosen
  {
    hangmanObject.numLives--;
    document.getElementById("numLives").innerHTML = hangmanObject.numLives;
    hangmanObject.incorrect.push(userGuess);
    document.getElementById("LettersGuessed").innerHTML = hangmanObject.incorrect;
  }
  console.log(hangmanObject.empty);
  if (hangmanObject.empty.indexOf(" _ ") === -1) {
    hangmanObject.numWins++;

    // console.log("i won");
    document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = hangmanObject.numWins;
    document.getElementById("Play").innerHTML = "Play Again? Y/N";
    document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    // Determines which exact key was selected. Make it lowercase
      var Choice = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
      if (Choice === 'y') {
        hangmanObject.numLives = 10;
        displayChosenWord();
      }
    }

  }
  if (hangmanObject.numLives <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("lose").innerHTML = "You Lose";
  }
} 

displayChosenWord();
document.onkeyup = gameKeyUp;
```

```html
<div id="numLives"></div>
<div id="blanks"></div>
<div id="LettersGuessed"></div>
<div id="wins"></div>
<div id="Play"></div>
<div id="lose"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. Two things I dont understand are, is this part: document.onkeyup = gameKeyUp; Are you calling the function, gamekeyup(event) with that line of code? And why do you have the: displayChosenWord();
document.onkeyup = gameKeyUp;                                                                    at the bottom of the page. Arent you already calling them within functions?

Comment: and what does that event argument do in the gameKeyUp(event)

Comment: the `event` argument has a reference to the Event object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) created by the user when pressing (releasing in this case) a key. Actually this object will be a KeyboardEvent (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). When you assign a callback function to the `onkeyup` property of an object, this function will always receive this event as first argument, and will be called when the event happens. That's why the `gameKeyUp` function defines the parameter, so it can use it to retrieve the key code after the key is pressed.